# Javascript to evaluate contains method on a <tr> or the entire table

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and it works when there are rows  in a table. however I need to add a contains logic where rowCount=0 if td contains "There are no items to show in this view".

https://jsfiddle.net/xnyLq1na/

```
var rowCount = $(".ms-WPBody tr").not(":has(th)").length;
if ($('.ms-WPBody tr >td:contains(there are no items)')
{
    alert ("found it");
    rowCount = 0;    
}
$(".rowCount").text("Num of rows: " + rowCount);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed the logic, fetching the html inside `<a>` tag and then comparing to see if it contains the required String.

you were missing a `)` after `("there are no items")')` too.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var rowCount = $(".ms-WPBody tr").not(":has(th)").length;
        var x = $('.ms-WPBody tr td  a').html();
        //alert(x.indexOf("there are no items"));
        if(x.indexOf("There are no items") !== -1){
        //alert ('found it');
        rowCount = 0;   
        }

         $(".rowCount").text("Num of rows: " + rowCount);
    });
```

**EDIT Update**:- changed the logic, fetching the html inside `<a>` tag and then comparing to see if it contains the required String.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sudhansu23/rsrrzpdn/1/)

Comment: Actually, is doesnt work when I have td rows with data. http://jsfiddle.net/wf0h544y/

Comment: thats because you don't have jQuery included in the fiddle and you haven't bound the jQuery function in `$(document).ready(function(){})`.Actually was the case with your first fiddle too

Comment: ok i checked the jquery framework and added $(document).ready piece . anything else I am missing.

Comment: what I am saying is that there is text that has "there are no items" in the the <td> so the count should be 2 not zero.

Comment: @ShawnTorres check the updated answer and the fiddle!

Comment: perfect. Thanks buddy for your detailed help. I truly appreciated it.

Comment: @ShawnTorres you're welcome. keep in mind, the indexOf() operation is case sensitive.

Comment: gotcha. Thanks again for your effort. I really appreciate it.